# Make meta box appear if the previous if not empty?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I have created a custom post type with the ability to have multiple featured images.  However, it would be nice if i didn't have 10 empty boxes on the post page asking for images...  I would like a featured image box to appear if the previous one has been populated..

So, if the featured image is set, then the Image #2 box will appear, and so on..

That way things will be less cluttered.  I am not sure if this is possible, any help would be appreciated.

I've tried:

```
if( $custom_meta_id['feature-image-3'] !== '') {

       new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
        'label' => '4th Image',
        'id' => 'feature-image-4',
        'post_type' => 'listing'
        )
    );

}
```

Comment: What is `MultiPostThumbnails`? Yes, you can do that but I don't know that I can guess at the correct code based on the information provided. There seems to be a lot of missing detail.

Comment: Also, the code posted is broken. You have a spurious single quote on the first line. Is that how you have it in your actual code or is that a typo when you posted here?

Comment: That is just a type here..  MultiPostThumbnails allows for multiple featured image boxes on my custom post type.. This is working perfectly.. I just want to only display one box, when it is populated the next box appears, etc..

Comment: It is possible to [edit] your question to fix the typo (I already did that for you).

Answer (score 0):

This more of a PHP + Logic question than a WordPress one but I think the solution is pretty simple.

1. Loop through some code to generate the existing boxes or the boxes with
   existing values
2. And always print one empty box for a new image.

For example:

```
foreach ($my_existing_boxes as $k => $v) {
  // not sure how your code works exactly
}
new MultiPostThumbnails(
  array(
    'label' => 'New Image',
    'id' => 'feature-image-new',
    'post_type' => 'listing'
  )
);
```